# Leaflet : remove layer if zoom level greater than 9

Tags: leaflet

I built a heatmap on Leaflet.
My first goal is to see the heatmap when you open the map. The second goal is not to view the heatmap if the zoom level is greater than 9.

I tried this :

```js
if (map.getZoom() > 9) {
    map.removeLayer(heatmapLayer);      
};
```

But it did not work.
Would you have any suggestions ?
Thanks !

---

**Here is the code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Application - version 1.0</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.3/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style_p.css" />

<style type="text/css"> 
html, body, #map {
margin: 0;
margin-top: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
};

</style>
    
</head>

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href="california.ico" />


<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.3/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="heatmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="heatmap-leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sloopjohnb.js"></script>
<script src="google.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet_search.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  

$(function() {
 

var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
var base = new L.TileLayer('http://129.206.74.245:8001/tms_r.ashx?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}');
var ggl2 = new L.Google('SATELLITE');

var heatmapLayer;
heatmapLayer = L.TileLayer.heatMap({
radius: 10,
opacity: 0.8,
gradient: {
0.45: "rgb(0,0,255)",
0.55: "rgb(0,255,255)",
0.65: "rgb(0,255,0)",
0.95: "yellow",
1.0: "rgb(255,0,0)"
}
});


var Data1={
max: 1,
data: sloopjohnb 
};
heatmapLayer.addData(Data1.data);

var baseMaps = {
"Fond OSM": osm,
"Fond de carte de base": base,
"Photo. aérienne Google" : ggl2

};

var overlayMaps = {
'Heatmap': heatmapLayer
};

map = new L.Map('map', {
minZoom : 1,
maxZoom : 11,
boxZoom : true,
layers: [base, heatmapLayer]
});

var controls = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {position: 'bottomright'});
controls.addTo(map);

map.addControl(L.control.search());
L.control.scale().addTo(map);
    
map.attributionControl.addAttribution('<a href="http://www.patrick wied.at/static/heatmapjs/">Heatmap.js</a>');
map.setView(new L.LatLng(39.291,-5.9765),2);


// Disparition de la heatmap en fct du zoom
map.on('zoomend', function () {
if (map.getZoom() > 9) {
map.removeLayer(heatmapLayer);
}
}); 

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14):

Are you sure you are creating the listener correctly?

For example, this seems like it should be called when the user zooms. So something like:

**Edited**

```js
map.on('zoomend', function () {
    if (map.getZoom() > 9 && map.hasLayer(heatmapLayer)) {
        map.removeLayer(heatmapLayer);
    }
    if (map.getZoom() < 9 && map.hasLayer(heatmapLayer) == false)
    {
        map.addLayer(heatmapLayer);
    }   
});
```

If you ONLY want the layer added/removed based on zoom, don't add it to your layer control here:

```js
var controls = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {position: 'bottomright'});
controls.addTo(map);
```

You will just have to make sure you are doing your adding/removing when it is necessary. Try messing with this set up a little and see where you get. Also, the [Documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) is well written regarding the use of [L.tileLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer)

Comment: Yes I did wrong. It works, thank you very much Chris ! I just have a last question. When I'm at the zoom level 10 and I activate the heatmap in the layer control, the heatmap is mapped. The problem is that the heatmap should not be mapped when the zoom level is greater than 9. Do you have an idea to solve that problem ? Thanks.

Comment: If you can post some more code samples or maybe a js fiddle it might be easier to distinguish what you may be doing wrong. But it sounds like you probably don't want to be adding and removing the heatmap layer with a control, just with the zoomend listener.

Comment: I edited my first post by adding the code. You can see the map at : http://ttga.alwaysdata.net/test10.html. And yeah, I'd prefer removing the layer with the zoomend. But if there's another solution I'm interested too. Thanks again Chris !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [leaflet-zoom-show-hide](https://github.com/auto-mat/leaflet-zoom-show-hide) library to do it. This will automatically show/hide your layers as you zoom.

```js
zsh = new ZoomShowHide(map);
var marker1 = L.marker([50.096, 14.425]);
//                    minzoom, maxzoom
zsh.addLayer(marker1, 10, 13);
var marker2 = L.marker([50.076, 14.425]);
zsh.addLayer(marker2, 8, null);
```