# Combine three maps with different zoom levels in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, layer

I am currently building my own map in Illustrator for a community of roleplayers. I am planning to make three versions of the map. One with little details, ment to be the most "zoomed out" version, a middle version with more details on smaller towns and cities, and then the fursthest zoomed version with detailed maps of cities.

Is it possible to combine three different maps in this way in leaflet when they have been made into tiles?

Thank you!

Comment: So now I have the image ready, and the best way for this project is to make it into tiles. How do I make two different sets of tiles show at different zoom levels?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "map" you mean "raster image", i.e. a `.jpg` or `.png` image. The word "map" has a different meaning when used in a technical context.

> Is it possible to combine three different maps in this way in leaflet when they have been made into tiles?

You don't neccesarily need tiles. Sounds like your use case could be covered with three [`L.ImageOverlay`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#imageoverlay)s, and making sure that they are [dynamically added/removed to/from the map at different zoom levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017318/leaflet-remove-layer-if-zoom-level-greater-than-9).

This assumes that the three images have the same map projection, and that you know the bounding boxes for each of them, and that no image is larger than 16000 pixels wide or high. If they are larger than that, consider [making map tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285483/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-map-tiles-for-leafletjs) instead.

If you choose tilelayers, you can either leverage the [`minZoom`/`maxZoom` options of `L.TileLayer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tilelayer) or create a set of tiles which uses a different original image for different zoom levels (i.e. slice the images so that the zoom levels for the output tiles for each slice operation are different).

Comment: On an unrelated note: one of my favourite examples of fantasy cartography is actually https://www.dungeonetics.com/golarion-geography/

Comment: Yes, I meant an image, such as a jpg or png. Thank you very much for your suggestions - the first alternative seems to be the one suiting my needs. I will look into!

Comment: BTW, if you plan to make several high-scale maps for cities, you can use one `L.ImageOverlay` for each - simpler and cleaner than creating a huge image for putting them together.